# MVC 5 Helper error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, helper, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this very short custom helper

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Colibri.HtmlHelpers
{
    public static class CustomHelper
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString SearchBar(this HtmlHelper helper, string type)
        {
            return new MvcHtmlString("<input type=\"text\" placeholder =\"Recherche...\" id=\"" + type + "-Search\" class=\"Search-Input\"/>");
        }
    }
}
```

In the Razor Web.config I added the namespace in the proper section:

```
<add namespace="Colibri.HtmlHelpers" />
```

An I just want to call it from a view with this code:

```
@Html.SearchBar("Article")
```

Here I get this error:

> Error  CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Colibri.HtmlHelpers.CustomHelper.SearchBar(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string)' and 'Colibri.HtmlHelpers.CustomHelper.SearchBar(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string)'

If I don't add the namespace in Web.config, it says:

> Error  CS1061  'HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'SearchBar' and no extension method 'SearchBar' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, it's got nothing to do with different namespaces - it's just you've got the same method signature declared in two places. Try searching `SearchBar` method in whole project and check.

Comment: CS0121 usually appears when 2 assemblies, classes or methods with different version exist in a project. Use full namespace or change method's name if you think naming conflict is behind the issue.

Comment: I already checked for that, assuming I forget I did something with the same name a long time ago, but no.

It's really the same reference. And when I call the method, it shows me the same signature twice.

Quite weird.

Comment: I tried Fully qualified name; I I get this error:

Error CS0433 The type 'Julien' exists in both 'Colibri, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'App_Code.vmsvzsyo, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' Colibri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your help.

I found out the issue: I just moved the .cs file from App_Code directory to another one.

It works fine now.